# How to communicate between Activity and Threads created by other Actvity

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity, communication

When you have 2 activities ( A and B ) and A is the MainActivity, now you start your App and A starts B.
B is a activity with a Dialog interacting with the user, creating a Bluetooth Connection and 2 Threads, 1 Receiving and one Sending.
Now, what is the best way to send the Information from A to the threads of B and the other way round? [image: Look here.]

First I used a static WeakReference, but I heard this causes a lot of problems, so I want to ask for a more common solution.

Please keep in mind, when starting an Activity from another Activity, you can only pass Serializable Objs and simple data. So it is not possible to use a Handler that way.

Here is the static WeakReference I used:

```java
public class T1 extends Thread{
private static WeakReference<T1> weak_T1;


public void T1 (){
weak_T1 = new WeakReference<T1> (This);
}

public static WeakReference getWeakReverence() {
    return weak_T1;
}

}
```

Here is a way to look for a running Thread in the stack:

```java
for (Thread thread : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) { 
    if (thread.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("T1")){ 
    T1A =thread; 
     }else if (thread.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("T2")){ 
     T2A =thread; 
     } 
}
```

Also possible solution:

```java
public class example extends Thread {
    private static example instance;

  private example() {
  }

  public static example getIsntance(){
    if(instance == null){
      instance = new example();
    }

    return instance;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just curious, how do you prevent the system from destroying Activity A while Activity B is showing?

Comment: @greeble31 Well A is parent of B, so A is just onPause not onDestroy.
Or maybe I don't understand your question, but why should A be destryed?

Comment: @greeble31 just to be clear, after the Threads are started Activity B is finished and A is in foreground again.

Comment: What I'm getting at is, you can't guarantee that Activity A stays in the "paused" state (or actually the "stopped/hidden", state in this case) for any length of time. As mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#activity-lifecycle), a stopped Activity "...will often be killed by the system when memory is needed elsewhere". Trying to communicate with an offscreen Activity is a no-no. You need to save the thread results somewhere (like a Service or even a static reference) and then have Activity A pick up that information after it resumes.

Comment: What do you think about the "get Thread in Stack"-solution?
The risk is getting a nullpointer exception but I can't think of other Problems.

Comment: I'd say that's a bad idea. Not dangerous, necessarily, but overcooked. Your question could be stated in this way: "I want to pass a complex, unserializable object (`Thread`) created in Activity B, to Activity A". In any other situation, this would be a trivial operation, using an assignment operator (`=`). People tend to overthink things with Activities b/c it's not always clear how they're supposed to communicate. The fact is you can just use a static reference.

Comment: Now, if you search for that on SO, you'll find people swearing against it, due to memory leaks. But if you set the reference in Activity B's `onBackPressed()`, and grab it (and clear it) in Activity A's `onResume()`, there is no memory leak. It _is_ a trivial operation, using an assignment operator (two or three times, in this case, but nevertheless...)

Comment: @greeble31 sorry, but I really want to understand this. :D
Look at my Question again, I made a WeakReference to my Thread, this works fine for me to get Information out of the Thread, what do you think about this?

Can you maybe write an example (as answer) and show me how you would handle the WeakReference according to a activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `WeakReference` probably isn't what you want, here. That is, presuming that your Thread object either does not terminate, or somehow maintains some information useful to Activity A after Activity B has stopped. If you use a `WeakReference`, it might become "null" as soon as Activity B ends, and the thread terminates. Just use regular old strong references. It'll ensure T1, and the information contains, continues to exist until you're done with it.

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity
{
    private T1 t1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        t1 = startMyThread();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        ActivityA.tempT1 = t1;

        //This technique presumes that Activity A is guaranteed to resume after a 
        //back button press, based on the arrangement of your backstack, etc. If
        //Activity A is started via some other means (e.g., an explicit startActivity(),
        //finish(), etc.), then this reference will have to be set prior to
        //that call, as well, in order to establish the appropriate "happens before" relationship.
        //If you fail to ensure that Activity A resumes after this point, you will
        //risk a memory leak.

        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

public class ActivityA extends Activity
{
    public static T1 tempT1 = null;
    private T1 t1;

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        if(tempT1 == null)
        {
            //Apparently, Activity B hasn't executed yet. Provide the user with a button to start it.
        }
        else
        {
            t1 = tempT1;
            tempT1 = null;     //To avoid a memory leak

            //We just retrieved the reference that Activity B left for us.
            //Now, change UI states so that the user can see information about t1.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since every activity goes through onResume() we could pass nearly everything between Activites this way or not? Like a handler for example.

Comment: Yes, personally I never do this  (I use a `Service` b/c it is needed for other reasons) but as long as you can establish the "happens before" relationship, this is safe.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
Have a nice Day.

Comment: Just to make this complete:
If we set a ParentActivity in Manifest, we can make sure, which activity will be started (either resume or create) after Activity B is finished.
[look at android:parentActivityName](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element)

Comment: can you maybe add an example, how to create a background service from A (anything extending Service.class) and how I could bind A and B to it?
I know you already answered the question, but this would be really helpful :)

Comment: @HydroHeiperGen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10585077/6759241) answer has a pretty typical `Service` example.

Comment: Hey I just learned about a singleton Thread what I think also could work very good. What do you think about this?

Comment: @HydroHeiperGen Not sure what you mean. Besides, how could anything be simpler than using the assignment operator?

Comment: check my edited Answer, the last added code example.

Comment: I would say yes, just be careful of memory leaks.